# Are $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ order isomorphic?

Tags: order-theory

The ordering on the first set is reverse lexicographic and the order of the second set is the usual ordering of reals.

My intuition tells me that the answer is no. The only isomorphism between those two sets that I know of is the one that interleaves the decimal digits of the numbers in a pair (the elements of the first set) and that one definitely doesn't preserve the order.

To do this I would have to attach the decimal digits of the first number to the end of the decimal digits of the second one, and that can't really be done since there are infinitely many of them.

This is far from formal, so I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is indeed negative. A relatively elementary solution would be to note that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ can be partitioned into uncountably many disjoint non-degenerate intervals (they contain at least two points each).

If there was an order isomorphism, then the partition would induce a partition of $[0,1]$ into uncountably many intervals (note that the order isomorphism maps intervals to intervals).

However in every interval in $[0,1]$ there is a rational number, so there is no uncountable partition into uncountably many disjoint intervals.

(Not to mention that those intervals would be closed, and if $[0,1]$ is partitioned into closed intervals, then the Baire category theorem tells us that it is necessarily a one-part partition, namely $\{[0,1]\}$.)

Comment: Nobody is upvoting your post, that leaves only me to do it.

Comment: Heh, thanks. In retrospect, I think it's an elementary version of your answer. (I would reciprocate a vote, but I can't vote your answer twice... :-))

Comment: That kind of splitting into a partition is not only a good solution for this problem, but also something I didn't think about before. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to see that they are not isomorphic is to note that in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ the subset $\{(1/2,x):x\in [0,1]\}$ is uncountable and discrete in the order topology..

Comment: Huh, yeah. I think the machinery there is a bit too advanced. Is there a simpler formulation? To clarify, this is a question on a test, and we definitely didn't cover order topologies.

Comment: @LukaHorvat what are you allowed to use?

Comment: I can only guess, but it's likely that I should find some invariant that holds for order isomorphic sets and show that it's true for one and not the other.