# Can $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ be partitioned into uncountably many disjoint non-degenerate intervals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108308/are-0-1-times0-1-and-0-1-order-isomorphic/1108342#1108342), @Asaf said that $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ can be partitioned into uncountably many disjoint non-degenerate intervals (they contain at least two points each), while $[0,1]$ can NOT be partitioned into uncountably many disjoint non-degenerate intervals.

Since $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and $[0,1]$ are equinumerous, I think that if $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ can be partitioned into uncountably many disjoint non-degenerate intervals, so can $[0,1]$.

What's wrong with my reasoning? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sure. How about $\{ [0,1]\times\{y\}\}_{y\in[0,1]\}}$ ? The point is, what do you consider an interval in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with your reasoning is that a one-to-one correspondence between $[0,1]$ and $[0,1]^2$ will not send
intervals to intervals.

Comment: Is it that the mapping just sends intervals to sets, not intervals to intervals?

Comment: Yes, it is that.

Comment: Thank you so much!